# False positive Sonar S1452 on return type containing generic of wildcard generic in java

Tags: java, generics, sonarqube, false-positive

I have a function similar to:

```
public MyService<DTO<?>> getMyService(){ ... }
```

Which means, get an instance of `MyService` that works for `DTO` of any generic type.

And I get a sonar s1452 message [Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1452). However I think it is a false positive. But, am I missing somehting?

Here is my thought: when using generic in a return type in a similar way as described in the sonar doc, e.g. `List<?>` it is indeed a code smell because such type cannot really be used. And if someone means a List of anything, then they should use `List<Object>`. But when returning a generic of generic, like `List<List<?>>` it just means a list of list of anything that can be used without knowing the second level generic (e.g. to get the length of each sublist). Moreover, returning a `List<List<Object>>` would require to rebuild all the sublist, which in many case would have a whole different meaning.

In my actual use case, the service of generic dto, I don't need to know the dto type argument because the dto can manage that. What I actually need is a way to serialize the data contained in the dto (into an output stream), and the dto comes with a serializer. You can see it as the dto having a method `serializeTo(OutputStream)` for which the generic need not be known.

So my question:

- Is it correct to detect a s1452 on a generic of generic (and if so, why) ?
- And if it is, is there a way not to do that?

**A more complete example fitting my use case**

```
interface DTO<T> {
  public T getData();
  public Serializer<T> serializer; // Serializer can write T to OutputStream

  default void writeTo(OutputStream output){
    serializer.write(getData(), output);
  }
}
class StringDTO implement DTO<String> { ... }
class DoubleDTO implement DTO<Double> { ... }

interface MyService<D> {
  public void process(D d);
}
class DTOService implement MyService<DTO<?>>{
  public void process(DTO<?> dto){
    OutputStream outputStream = // ...
    dto.writeTo(outputStream);
  }
}

// and in some spring configuration class
@Bean
public MyService<DTO<?>> getDtoService(){ // sonar error
  return new DTOService();
}
```

Comment: @Ravindra_Ranwala how does the question you gave answer my question? I ask about generic of generic? And also about a way to do it differently. None of those are answered in the question you closed mine as duplicate of...

Comment: `public <T> MyService<DTO<T>> getMyService()`? A X(?) can never be assigned to a `X<String>` as it might be an `X<Integer>`.

Comment: I thought about it (and should have written it I guess). The problem is that I would have to instantiate a different `MyService` for each `T`, while it is designed to work for any: the subtype `T` does not need to be known to `MyService<DTO<?>>`, only that it is a `DTO`.

Comment: Actually, I start to think that I don't agree with the whole s1452. Of course it is a complex design that should be avoided if something simpler does the work. However, it is perfectly find if it is done on purpose: you know and can use the type, but not the generic. Here my point is to decouple MyService. The less it knows the better.

Comment: Then the DTO maybe should not have a type parameter. Or you might want a `Class<T> type`parameter  to getDtoService. I cannot tell.

Comment: In your case, I'd suggest to split `DTO<T>` in two interfaces. It would appear `MyService` only needs the non-generic half. This solution should not be considered a hack; the need to split the interface strongly suggests the combined interface was already violating one or more SOLID principles. For your convenience, you could still decide to define an abstract class `DTO<T>` implementing both interfaces. I think that makes more sense than a default method, that has `serializer` (obviously an implementation detail) poluting your interface.